# Failed to found document with an error Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401

Tags: google-apps-script, blob, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to download a google docs file as pdf on running apps script script.

```
//Code.gs

function run() {
  const documentId = 'somDocId';
  try {
    // Get the document using document id
    const doc = Docs.Documents.get(documentId);
    
    
    
    createPDF(doc.title);
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer) - Handle exception from Docs API
    console.log('Failed to found document with an error %s', err.message);
  }
}


function createPDF(pdfName) {
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/somDocId/export?format=pdf";

  const params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');

  // below instead of saving to drive, I want to directly download in current window
  const folder = getFolderByName_("someFolder");

  folder.createFile(blob);
}


run();
```

also I get below error for this

```
Failed to found document with an error Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><style...
```

Comment: I proposed an answer by guessing your current situation. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your current situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your showing script, when `documentId` and `url` and `folder` are valid values, your script works fine while 2 PDF files are created because of `run();` of the global. So, from your following showing an error message,

> Failed to found document with an error Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: <style...

If `documentId` is an invalid value, I think that an error like `Requested entity was not found.` occurs. So, your showing script, I guess `documentId` is a valid value. And, if `url` is an invalid value, I guess that your showing error message. So, I'm worried that you might directly use the URL of `https://docs.google.com/document/d/somDocId/export?format=pdf`. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please set your valid Google Document ID to `documentId`. And, run the function `run()`. By this, the script is run.

```js
function run() {
  const documentId = 'somDocId';

  try {
    const doc = Docs.Documents.get(documentId);
    createPDF(doc.title, documentId); // Modified
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed to found document with an error %s', err.message);
  }
}

function createPDF(pdfName, documentId) { // Modified
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/document/d/${documentId}/export?format=pdf`; // Modified

  const params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  const folder = getFolderByName_("someFolder");
  folder.createFile(blob);
}

// run(); // Removed.
```

- By the way, in your situation, the following modification might be able to be also used.

  - From

    ```js
    const doc = Docs.Documents.get(documentId);
    createPDF(doc.title, documentId); // Modified
    ```
  - To

    ```js
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
    createPDF(doc.getName(), documentId); // Modified
    ```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, in your showing script, the function `getFolderByName_` is not showing. In this modification, it supposes that the function `getFolderByName_` has already been declared elsewhere, and a valid value is returned. Please be careful about this.